# Introduction to Memcached

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I am trying to use [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) right now, and I am a little confuse about this:

First, do I need to make a class for Memcached? like this: [click me!](http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php) or is it automatically works? do I just need to make a connection to the memcached server and then I can cache data?

**UPDATE**

When I tried to use the code *exiang* provided, my output in all of the `var_dump`s are `boolean false`. Anybody knows why is this happened?

**UPDATE PART 2**

When I tried to use this code `echo $m->getResultMessage(),"\n";` it returns:

> SERVER HAS FAILED AND IS DISABLED UNTIL TIMED RETRY

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have enabled the php memcache module, it looks like this in your phpinfo
[image]

Make sure your memcached server is running

Then, you can use it directly like this:
http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php

```
<?php
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);

$m->set('int', 99);
$m->set('string', 'a simple string');
$m->set('array', array(11, 12));
/* expire 'object' key in 5 minutes */
$m->set('object', new stdclass, time() + 300);


var_dump($m->get('int'));
var_dump($m->get('string'));
var_dump($m->get('array'));
var_dump($m->get('object'));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the output on the webpage is `boolean false`

Comment: all of the `var_dump`s are returning `boolean false`